# Is this possible to communicate TCP Port for incoming message from web service

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Is this possible to make a tcp IP communication to receive any content which is waiting, from C# code on demand ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/312530/Calling-Webservice-Using-TCP-IP-from-any-Programmi which utilizes tcp connection to consume a web service. You may want to check it.

Comment: It's vice versa. I am having web service and need to look for an IP for incoming messages from Webservice. Kind of listening.

Comment: so you want to see if a specific IP uses your web service , am i right?

Comment: Third party will be sending the message to my port which is configured at my end. So I will be looking that port to see any message is waiting for me receive.